# automatically select correct user folder on different machines

Tags: python, working-directory

I have a question. I work on two devices wherein I have two folders that contain the files that I use. Nonetheless, I find it quite annoying to continuously change the paths/directories due to the user name differences between these systems. Is there a way I can ‘soft code’ this better? The directory that contains my project files is : `C:\Users\myname\Documents\Project`

So, only the `\myname\` is different between systems.

Comment: Check out the `%userprofile%` environment variable.

Comment: If you mean that you're referring to those directories within the code, then you could use `os.getlogin()` and concatenate it with the path.

Comment: You can use `os.path.expanduser("~")` which yields the current user dir on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as follows:

```
import os
```

Get current working directory:

```
work_dir = os.getcwd()
```

You likely only get `C:\Users\myname` when you look at `work_dir`, but this if-statement helps in case you will get the full path already. Here you join the `work_dir` path with additional paths:

```
if 'Documents' in work_dir: 
    work_dir = work_dir
else: 
    work_dir = os.path.join(work_dir, 'Documents', 'Project')
```

Finally, set this directory as your working directory:

```
os.chdir(work_dir)
```

You can even print the files in the directory to make sure you are indeed in the
correct (Project) directory:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    print(f)
```